Why does assigning one DataFrame to another in Pandas not create a new copy when the Copy-on-Write feature is enabled?
The Pandas documentation describes Copy-on-Write (CoW) behavior as: "CoW means that any DataFrame or Series derived from another in any way always behaves as a copy." Pandas CoW Documentation Why then, when I assign one DataFrame to another, does it not create a new copy?
You can see in the image I enable CoW and then assign df2 to df1. I would assume that df2 is a distinct copy of df1, but they reference the same memory location.
Example output

There is no "write" happening in your code: df2 = df1 is a python-level renaming of the object.

And Python does not provide any way to "hook" into = assignments, so there is no way for Pandas to act like you're expecting. It will always be a reference assignment, regardless of the types of the objects.

"when I assign one DataFrame to another" what does this mean, exactly? You don't assign an object to another object, you assign an object to a name.

" I would assume that df2 is a distinct copy of df1, but they reference the same memory location." no, this has nothing to do with pandas, this is core Python semantics. Assignment never copies. I closed as a duplicate of a classic question about list objects, but this applies to all assignment statements regardless of the objects involved.

Please, in the future, post all code in the question itself as formatted text. Do not post images of code, or links to code, or links to images of code

Also, you should read the following post by StackOverflow legend Ned Batchelder regarding the semantics of Python with respects to names and objects: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

The dataframe you are assigning is the same object in memory, you are just changing the variable name in which it is being recognized by your python code.
